# Transforming an n-dimensional linear system of second order ODEs to n independent second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, linear-transformations

Suppose I have a homogeneous second order linear system of ODEs. $$\ddot{y}_i = -\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{ij}y_j, \,\text{for }i=1,...,n$$ Also vectorially denoted $$ \ddot{\vec{y}}= -\boldsymbol{\alpha}\vec{y}. $$ I am assuming that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is of rank $n$.

Then I wanted to decouple these coupled equations so then imposing a sinusoidal solutions $\vec{y}=e^{i\omega t}(\vec{e}_1 + ... + \vec{e}_n)$ where $\{\vec{e}_i\}$ are the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then seeing that $\ddot{\vec{y}}=-\omega^2\vec{y}$, we are now dealing with an eigenvalue problem:$$ \boldsymbol{\alpha}\vec{y}= \omega^2\vec{y}$$ where the eigenvalues are $\omega^2$. Now let the eigenvectors be $\vec{\eta}_j$ for the $j^{th}$ eigenvalue $\omega_j^2$, then they form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\boldsymbol{T}=[\vec{\eta}_1...\vec{\eta}_n]$ then applying this transformation to both sides of the vector ODE (knowing $\boldsymbol{T}$ will commute with $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$), we can solve the n independent set of equations:
$$ \ddot{\vec{\eta}}_j=-\omega_j^2\vec{\eta}_j.$$

Whose solution can be transformed back to $\vec{y}$ using $\boldsymbol{T}$. (Please correct me if I made an error thus far).

My question now relates to the "Normal Modes" of the system, clearly these are not the normal modes since there's no guarantee that the eigenvectors are orthogonal, as $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is NOT assumed to be symmetric. What is this transformation I did to the ODES? It seems they are now decoupled but not the "normal modes" which has a main property that the modes are orthogonal.
Is there a way to transform these modes to the normal modes? Also how does one go about getting the normal modes of such a system when presented with a non-symmetric matrix?

Any elaboration is helpful! Also a reference to this area perhaps might be useful!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I assume that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is a rank n matrix.

EDIT2:

I assume that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is diagonalizable, such that we are guaranteed that its eigenvectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: One major problem in your derivation is that the eigenvectors of a non-symmetric matrix need not span $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The canonical example is the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$for which the only eigenvector is $[1 \; 0]^T$ (up to normalization).  You might play around with the corresponding ODE system ($\ddot{x} = -y, \ddot{y} = 0$) to see what happens in this case.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert but if I know that these are the "equations of motion" involving the  n "degrees of freedom" of my system, so the rank of said matrix must be n which guarantees their eigenvectors being a basis, or is that not correct?

Comment: I should have clarified perhaps, I'm definitely assuming the matrix is of rank n.

Comment: That definitely makes a big difference (I make an edit to put that information at the top.)  I will have to think about this further.

Comment: Even with the assumption that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is of rank $n$, that's not enough to ensure that its eigenvectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Consider $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$instead.  It has rank 2 but it only has one eigenvector (same as my example above).

Comment: @MichaelSeifert okay good point, so the condition to ensure that its eigenvectors span $\mathbb{R}^n$ is for $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ to be diagonalizable. I will think about the case where it's not, but it seems to me what I'm trying to get at it will always have the matrix $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ be diagonalizable. So in that case it is diagonalizable and we have the eigenvectors forming a basis, now back to the original question - what can I do?

Comment: @LostInEuclids5thPostulate Regardless of rank, in the nonsymmetric case you have to look at the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) rather than the diagonalization.

Comment: @LostInEuclids5thPostulate Also, why do you expect the modes to be normal? Normal modes are not a general feature of 2nd order ODEs; they only appear in special cases, such as when there is a potential $U$ satisfying $\mathbf{\alpha}=-\nabla U$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is diagonalizable, that means there exists a non-singular matrix $T$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $\alpha = T D T^{-1}$.  Under this assumption, we can write
$$
\ddot{\vec{y}} = - \boldsymbol{\alpha} \vec{y} = - \mathbf{T} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{T}^{-1} \vec{y} 
\quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \left(\mathbf{T}^{-1} \vec{y}\right) = - \mathbf{D} \left( \mathbf{T}^{-1} \vec{y} \right) 
$$
In this form, we can find a set of $n$ solutions to this system by taking vectors $\vec{y}$ such that $\mathbf{T}^{-1} \vec{y} = \hat{e}_j$, or (in your notation) $\vec{y} = \mathbf{T} \hat{e}_j = \vec{\eta}_j$.  We can see that since $\mathbf{T}$ is not necessarily orthogonal, we have done a *similarity transformation* on the space of solutions, and the "normal mode" vectors are the image of the standard basis under the action of $\mathbf{T}$.

This is in contrast to the typical case, where matrix $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is symmetric and the transformation from "conventional" coordinates to the "normal modes" is an orthogonal transformation.  In fact, this is an "if and only if" statement:  the spectral theorem states that a real $n \times n$ matrix is symmetric if and only if its eigenvectors form an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  This means that if there *was* a way to find a set of "normal mode" vectors that was orthogonal, it would mean that $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ was symmetric in the first place.

It seems to me (and I welcome correction on this matter) that the $\vec{\eta}_j$ vectors are in some sense "the best we can do" if the matrix $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is not symmetric.  We still have the property that the general solution can be written as a superposition of oscillatory functions (or linear functions or exponentials, if $\mathbf{D}$ has any zero or negative entries on the diagonal).  Further, the relative amplitudes & phases of each component of the oscillation are encoded in the vectors $\vec{\eta}$, and their squared frequencies are the diagonal entries of $\mathbf{D}$.  The only property we lose is the orthogonality;  but depending on what we want to do with these normal modes, that may not be a huge loss.

Finally, it is worth exploring what we mean by "orthogonal" in this situation.  [These notes on normal modes and orthogonality](http://rickbradford.co.uk/NormalModesandOrthogonality.pdf) appear to address some of your concerns.  In particular, for a conventional ODE system $\mathbf{M} \ddot{\vec{y}} = - \mathbf{K} \vec{y}$ (with $\mathbf{M}$ symmetric & positive definite, and $\mathbf{K}$ symmetric), the normal modes are orthogonal under the inner product defined by $\mathbf{M}$ (i.e., $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle_\mathbf{M} \equiv \sum_{i,j} x_i M_{ij} y_j$  rather than $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y}\rangle \equiv \sum_{i} x_i y_i$.  This suggests that if we can find symmetric matrices $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{K}$ such that $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \mathbf{M}^{-1} \mathbf{K}$, then we could define a modified notion of orthogonality for our modes.  But whether this is possible in general, I do not know.